# USA write-in ballots

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, voting, federalism, presidential-election

Disclosure: I do not live in the USA and so am only picking up bits of American news from various places.

What I'm picking up on is that one of the larger things in the United States is a legal argument whether Donald Trump can be listed on state primaries, because some states have barred him based on Section 3 of the [14th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution](https://www.archives.gov/milestone-documents/14th-amendment).

My question is not on the 14th Amendment, but about write-ins on ballots.

If the U.S. Supreme Court does rule that states can bar him from being listed on the ballot as a printed name, what happens if enough of his supporters decided to list him as as a write-in name on their ballot?

Would the ballot be considered "spoilt" and discarded, and therefore that person has wasted their ballot, meaning they haven't even cast a vote for their 2nd choice candidate?

Comment: "one of the larger things **in the colonies**" Ha! Ha! Must be confusing because all American politicians are insurrectionists from your perspective.

Comment: “their 2nd choice candidate”? AFAIK, the US does not use instant run off aka preferential voting - one ballot, one vote.

Comment: @DaleM There are some places that do use ranked choice. For instance, Alaska does. I'm not sure whether it has it for the presidential election.

Comment: @DaleM I think the point was to express that voters likely have a second choice candidate ("who would I vote for if I couldn't vote for my preferred candidate"), even if they can't express that preference officially.

Comment: @DaleM Maine and Alaska are the only two states with IRV. Both do use it in federal elections, but I don't know if they do in Presidential primary elections. None of the three states with majority to win requirements (GA, LA, and one other that I can't recall) use it in Presidential primaries or Presidential general elections.

Comment: This could easily vary from one state to another.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm fairly sure they are barred from running in the UK! Didn't pay their taxes, did they.

Answer (score 12):

> If the U.S. Supreme Court does rule that states can bar him from being
> listed on the ballot as a printed name, what happens if enough of his
> supporters decided to list him as as a write-in name on their ballot?
>
> Would the ballot be considered "spoilt" and discarded, and therefore
> that person has wasted their ballot, meaning they haven't even cast a
> vote for their 2nd choice candidate?

If a candidate is legally determined to be ineligible to hold a public office based upon Section 3 of the 14th Amendment, then write-in votes cast for that candidate in the general election would not be counted. The ballots of people making that write-in vote would be wasted.

**Delegates For Candidates Disqualified After A Primary or Caucus Is Held**

If a candidate in a Presidential primary or caucus, wins delegates to a party national convention, and that candidate is only later disqualified, however, those delegates would then become uncommitted delegates who could shift their support to a new candidate.

Something similar routinely happens in the primary and caucus season of Presidential elections, when people vote for candidates who drop out of the race before the time to select of nominee for their political party arrives.

**Footnote Regarding Democratic Write-In Ballots In New Hamsphire**

On the other hand, incumbent President Joe Biden, a Democrat, has been excluded from the Democratic party primary ballot in the New Hampshire primary being held today on January 23, 2024, despite being the only serious candidate for the Democratic Presidential nomination (twenty-one vanity candidates for the Democratic Presidential nomination will appear on the New Hampshire Democratic primary ballot), and despite the fact that Biden is constitutionally qualified to serve as President, as he is currently doing, is undisputed.

Polling indicates that a supermajority will be writing in Joe Biden as their choice on that ballot.

***The way this state of affairs came to be is complicated and highlights the Byzantine nature of the process by which the U.S. chooses its President.***

The *Washington Post* [explains](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2024/01/23/why-biden-isnt-new-hampshire-primary-ballot/) what is going on there:

> New Hampshire is holding the first-in-the-nation primary elections on
> Tuesday, for both Democrats and Republicans. But the Democratic
> primary won’t have President Biden on the ballot. Voters will see the
> names of his 21 primary challengers instead — and space to write in a
> name.
>
> But even if one of his primary challengers wins in New Hampshire, it
> won’t change the electoral outcome of the Democratic nomination
> process. Barring a catastrophe, Biden will likely be Democrats’
> nominee. Here’s what’s going on with New Hampshire.
>
> The parties set their own primary calendars, but for decades
> Republicans and Democrats have followed roughly the same schedule:
> Iowa holds the first caucus, then New Hampshire holds the first
> primary. Republicans are still doing that this year.
>
> But **Democrats dramatically changed up their primary schedule for 2024.**
> **The party chose South Carolina, where there are far more Black voters**
> **than in mostly-White Iowa or New Hampshire. New Hampshire was supposed**
> **to go second alongside Nevada, then Michigan. Iowa was pushed way**
> **forward to March....**
>
> **The state is**
> **holding a primary anyway on Tuesday, for both Democrats and**
> **Republicans. New Hampshire’s election officials note that a**
> **decades-old state law requires it to be the first primary in the**
> **nation. (Iowa doesn’t count, because it’s a caucus.)**
>
> New Hampshire Democrats argued behind the scenes they didn’t care if
> they got penalized for breaking the rules. It’s a pretty low-stakes
> primary, given there’s no real question about who will be the nominee....
>
> The fight between the Democratic National Committee and New Hampshire
> over the calendar quickly got contentious. **The DNC decided to penalize**
> **New Hampshire by taking away its roughly two dozen delegates. The**
> **primary there is “meaningless,” the DNC declared this month, adding:**
> **"…[P]residential candidates should take all steps possible not to**
> **participate.”...**
>
> **The Biden campaign long ago decided to follow the party’s guidance and**
> **not compete there. “While the president wishes to participate in the**
> **Primary, he is obligated as a Democratic candidate for President to**
> **comply [with party rules],”...**
>
> Beyond New Hampshire, **Biden’s 21 primary challengers are hardly a**
> **factor, but one of them might win this primary. But the win will be**
> **symbolic, since the state has been deprived of its delegates....**
>
> **If Biden**
> **wins the New Hampshire primary, it would be through a write-in**
> **campaign being led by grassroots Democrats.** The Biden campaign is not
> involved in this, because he can’t compete in the state. But a group
> of New Hampshire Democratic Party leaders have launched a campaign to
> urge voters to write in his name, and it’s possible he could win that
> way. Still, write-in campaigns are historically difficult, and require
> a lot of voter education and outreach....
>
> **New Hampshire is also an open primary, meaning voters not registered**
> **with a party can choose which primary ballot they’d like.** It’s
> actually pretty normal in the state for independents who lean left to
> vote in the Republican primary to affect that outcome, for example.

Comment: As of a minute ago, 90% of precincts have reported in. Biden had 51.4% of the vote, all through write-ins, and there is about 14% that are write-in (almost certainly also for Biden?) that are marked as unprocessed. Next highest candidate is under 20%. So it looks like Biden will get all of New Hampshire's 0 delegates.

Comment: Kinda gotta feel bad for the 17ish people who thought maybe they were serious candidates, and got less than the 0.6% of [Vermin Supreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermin_Supreme).

Comment: @T.E.D. this morning he was up to 665! Amusingly, it's still 0.6%.

Comment: "when people vote for candidates who drop out of the race before the time to select of nominee for their political party arrives" -- there were votes last night for deSantis, even though he dropped out before the primary. He was still listed on the ballots since they were printed weeks ago.

Comment: -1 _If a candidate is legally determined to be ineligible to hold a public office based upon Section 3 of the 14th Amendment_ : The question was not regarding any eligibility to hold public office, but regarding a state's right to bar someone from its ballot.

Comment: @Vector The two issues are identical in this case because Colorado law requires candidates who appear on a primary ballot (the primary process is administered and paid for by state and county governments, not the political party in question), to be eligible to hold public office, and that requirement has repeatedly been affirmed in prior cases as constitutionally valid. So, SCOTUS will reach the Section 3 eligibility issue. Almost all, but not all, states have the same requirement, as does, IRRC, the RNC.

Comment: @ohwilleke - You don't know what issue SCOTUS may or may not touch. They may say that CO has the right to determine who is on their ballot **regardless**, without getting involved at all in the eligibility issue - which they may well want to avoid.

Comment: @Vector: Alternatively, they might specify that the theoretical possibility that 2/3 of both houses of Congress might vote to make Trump eligible sometime prior to January 6, 2025 would be sufficient basis to consider him "eligible" for purposes of Colorado balloting, while explicitly declining to say whether or not Trump would be eligible without such Congressional action.

Comment: @supercat - Yes. There are probably several ways they could dodge the issue - which they likely will.

Comment: "then write-in votes cast for that candidate in the general election would not be counted. The ballots of people making that write-in vote would be wasted": isn't that a matter of state law?  I am not aware of a federal statute requiring it, and the constitution itself certainly entertains the possibility of an unqualified candidate receiving a majority of votes of the electoral college.

Comment: @phoog All but a small handful of U.S. states, as a matter of state law, do not count the votes of candidates not qualified to hold the office in question.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Do most states go through the effort of ensuring that each and every registered write-in candidate is eligible before determining whether they have enough votes to make the issue relevant?  I would think that it would be more efficient, in cases where a plurality of the votes are write-ins, to ascertain the apparent winner, then vet for eligibility.  If the winner-apparent turns out to be ineligible, then vet the runner-up for eligibility, etc.

Comment: @supercat Usually, to get your write-in votes counted, you have to submit a short and simple form similar to a voter registration form, saying that you are eligible to hold the office and providing contact information. The state election law also generally provides a window of time where citizens can dispute a candidate's eligibility.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Did Biden submit such a form in New Hampshire?  By my understanding, the official campaign is effectively pretending the New Hampshire primary doesn't exist, and the write-in campaign is orchestrated by New Hampshire residents who don't want their state to be left out of the political process.

Comment: @supercat I don't have any easy way of knowing one way or the other. Given that the primary in NH allocates no Democratic party delegates, it may not even be a justiciable question.

Answer (score 11):

Merely having an invalid write-in does not spoil the ballot in general; it spoils only that vote. If the ballot is ranked-choice, further votes are counted, and if there are other votes on the ballot (for instance, there may be an initiative on the same ballot as the presidential ballot), those are also valid.

An example is this law from Washington state:

> Those parts of a ballot are invalid and no votes may be counted for those issues or offices where more votes are cast for the office or issue than are permitted by law; write-in votes do not contain all of the information required under RCW 29A.60.021; or that issue or office is not marked with sufficient definiteness to determine the voter's choice or intention.

https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=29A.60.040

Note that it says "those parts of a ballot are invalid", not "those ballots are invalid".

Comment: But the candidate being unqualified for the office does not appear on the list of reasons for invalidating part of a ballot.